# Find the last data entered in rows in Microsoft Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet of clients in column A and each week along the top row.  When a client attends I put a corresponding "1" in the week they attended.

I would like to insert a column that finds the last "1" in each client's row (their last attendance) and returns the date at the top of the column (the date of their last attendance)

Answer (score 2):

In your result column, on the first client row enter the formula

```
{=MAX(B$1:BA$1*B2:BA2)}
```

or, with the L1C1 notation:

```
{=MAX(L1C(-52):L1C(-1)*LC(-52):LC(-1))}
```

This is an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) which has more than one value as a result, you have to enter it without the <kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>}</kbd> and finish it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then Excel adds the <kbd>{</kbd> <kbd>}</kbd> to show it is an array formula.